# After “for" is noun or V-ing?

Tags: grammar, nouns, grammaticality-in-context

I have 2 sentences, what is true?

1. Data is too large for exporting
2. Data is too large for export

Please help to choose and explain why we choose the answer. 
Thanks so much!

Comment: Date *are* too large? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve seen this a lot here on ELL. People ask a question almost as if they assume one version is correct and therefore the other must not be correct.

In this case, I wouldn’t deem either of those “incorrect” (particularly if they are only meant as, say, a program’s error message). However, I do think a more natural way to express it would be:

> Data is too large ***to*** export.

Going back to your question, though, *for* is generally used as a preposition, so it’s object is usually a noun. However, a verb with an *-ing* ending is called a [**gerund**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund), which functions as a noun. That’s why either one of your originals can work.

Comment: You need to read [Not so fast!](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) on meta.